# Python and Dlib. AttributeError

Tags: python-3.x, dlib

I regulary use Dlib with Python 3.4, but now I need to use the dlib.get_face_chip() method (see [documentation](http://dlib.net/python/index.html#dlib.get_face_chip)) and continue having the following:

```
AttributeError: module 'dlib' has no attribute 'get_face_chip'
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it installs, Dlib configures to your system. Updating your system afterwards can break things.

I would uninstall and reinstall Dlib: `pip3 uninstall dlib`, `pip3 install dlib`

Comment: I will try as soon as I can and let you know. Thanks.